# VBA change first letter of word to upper case

Tags: vba, excel

What is the best way to change column headers from all caps to only the first letter of each word?

Thank you

Comment: Use this cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Proper(cell.Value)

Comment: As @yass mentioned. Look [here](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/convert-to-proper-case.html)

Answer (score 3):

Work with ***[WorksheetFunction.Proper Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838256.aspx)*** Which Capitalizes the first letter in a text string and any other letters in text that follow any character other than a letter, than set a loop through your columns Headings.

*Example*

```
Public Sub Example()
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Last = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Debug.Print Last ' Print on Immdiate Window

    With ActiveWorkbook
        For i = Last To 1 Step -1
            Debug.Print Cells(1, i).Value ' Print on Immdiate Window
            Cells(1, i).Value = WorksheetFunction.Proper(Cells(1, i).Value)
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: In native VBA, `strconv("PROPER", vbProperCase)` is **Proper**.